# how do I use a Rails4 date_field in a Slim template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

We are building a Rails 4 app. I have never worked with the Slim template system before. Does anyone know how I can use a Rails4 date_field in a Slim template?

Comment: was your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

In Slim, you'll just need to preface `date_field_tag` with `=` - i.e.:

```
= date_field_tag <whatever_params>
```

Or, if you're using this in the context of a form (as you appear to be), you could do something like this:

```
= form_for @some_object do |f|
  = f.date_field <whatever_params>
  = f.submit <whatever_params>
```